# Android - NavigationDrawer содержимое

Tags: xml, android, java

Доброго времени суток. Кто знает какой (примерно) каркас на [этом](http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/183e168c-180c-4127-8739-dbf80348af82.1397385882.png) скриншоте? Хочу сделать что-то подобное, но как реализовать не пойму. Пользуюсь библиотекой [jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu?files=1). В распоряжение дан целый .xml файл. Внутри него у меня ListView с элементами для загрузки данных с разных страниц. Выше хочу разместить кнопку для перехода в профиль (с аватаром и логином), еще выше - строку поиска. XML редактор говорит, что нельзя помещать ListView внутрь ScrollView. Как в таком случае сделать прокручивание .xml файла? Хотя бы примерный каркас увидеть, если не трудно))

p.s. добавлять Header'ы и Footer'ы, имхо, не совсем хорошо в моем случае, ибо появятся проблемы с содержимым при вызове метода onResume(), когда поменяется логин, или юзер из профиля выйдет...

Comment: Зачем вам использовать ListView у вас же там будет не более 20 элементов.
Используйте только ScrollVIew.    
Если все же хотите использовать ListView, то какие проблемы вы видите с добавлением header в  ListView?

Comment: Можно даже не использовать header, а просто в кастомном адаперте прописать отдельное создание кастомного View для кнопки переходв в профиль, когда position == 0, для остальных использовать обычные пункты меню, которые вы хотели :)

Comment: Andreich, у меня из MainActivity отправляет пользователя в LoginActivity если пользователь не авторизован. Когда авторизовываешься, то в хедере ничего не меняется. В onResume() пытаюсь удалить view, в итоге остаются пустые 2 пункта + новый пункт с "минипрофилем". А вот насчет того, чтобы цепляться за position, вот это идея, спасибо.

Comment: Хотя это, конечно, не профессионально))

Comment: Почему не профессионально? вполне себе прекрасный способ.

Comment: Да ладно?))

Comment: ну дело ваше, считать какой это способ. просто сравните, на сколько сложней будет логика, если добавлять header. Если у вас это не вышло, если логика сложней, значит легче запутаться. Так что я могу поставить под сомнение, какой вариант профессиональней